# Swift Quick/Nimble tests not running

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, quick-nimble

I'm trying to do a simple test to see if Quick and Nimble are working properly, but they're not. Here is my simple test which is supposed to break:

```
import Quick
import Nimble

class SomeSpec: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
        describe("bad test") {
            it("does not pass") {
                expect("good").to(equal("bad"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I run the test, I'll see output:

> Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.004) seconds

I don't know why zero tests are being run. I did install Quick and Nimble with Swift Package Manager instead of Cocoapods, if that might be a reason for the problem.

Answer (score 4):

To anyone still having an issue, it's already addressed in the latest Quick release - but unless you point version, default `pod install` installs Quick 4.0.0, while version 5.0.1 is already available. So add this to the podfile:

```
 pod 'Quick', '~> 5.0.1'
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the test class is not part of the test target, therefore it's not being run. Try deleting and re-adding it as per '[Xcode Help > Add a test class to a project](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.1/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/devd3b1da4c4)'.

And here are the steps to run this test successfully in a brand new project:

1. Create a new project (for demo purposes, on the options screen, uncheck 'Include Unit Tests'.
2. Add a test target as per '[Add a test target to a project](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.1/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/dev2ea31ea57)'.
3. Add Quick and Nimble pods to the test target.
4. Add a test class as per '[Xcode Help > Add a test class to a project](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.1/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/devd3b1da4c4)'.
5. Replace the content of the test class file with your snippet above.
6. Run the tests ('Product > Test').

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @elveatles I just added the exact steps I followed to run the test successfully. Can you give them a try and see if you run into any specific issues?

Comment: I didn't use Cocoapods before because it's buggy with Xcode 8.1 and Swift 3 which is why I was trying to use Swift Package Manger. So, I would use Cocoapods to add Quick and Nimble if it didn't break my project.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue, the issue was a Few API deprecated with quick and nimble so from our end we need to update the pod version.

The issue was already has been noticed and fixed
Ref: https://github.com/Quick/Quick/pull/1129

Tested with **Xcode 13.4**

Use the latest version for the Quick and Nimble

1. `pod 'Quick', '5.0.1'` Ref: https://github.com/Quick/Quick/releases
2. `pod 'Nimble', '10.0.0'` Ref: https://github.com/Quick/Nimble/releases